# Can the selected images from library be stored in an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uiimagepickercontroller

I have built a sample project on camera and library. Now, my question is can I store the images that I am selecting from library into an array? I am using this code.

```
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
[self.arrImages addObject:chosenImage];
```

Now by placing breakpoints, I came to know that, in my array always 1object is storing even after I chosen images for more than one times.

Can anyone give my any idea how can I do it?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have your arrImages alloc init?

Comment: Yup! Every time when I select image from library, I think its overwriting the previous one and so only 1 object is storing in my array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

//declare before NSMutableArray *_mutableArray;
_mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

....

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
 //dismiss UIImagePickerController
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];

//take image from anywhere
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

//store image into NSMutableArray
[_mutableArray addObject:image];


}
```

Comment: Perfect!! Got it! Appreciated! :) @iAnurag

Comment: Perhaps you made your array init every time your picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo.