# How to view stored images in an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I found a way to store images of `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` in an `NSArray` but I can not find a solution to view images in an `UIImageView` from the `NSArray`. Here is the link to store image:

[Can the selected images from library be stored in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558314/can-the-selected-images-from-library-be-stored-in-an-array)

Comment: Have you tried anything to fetch image from array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to iterate through that array...

```
for(UIImage *img in self.imageArray){
self.image = img;
}
```

Or imageView:

```
for(UIImageView *imgView in self.imageArray){
self.imageView = imgView;
}
```

Comment: thanks it is working,you forgot to add .image---- self.imageview.image=imgview

Comment: I'm glad that it helped. Accept this answer, so the others who have similiar problem can see it. Best regads.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you stored images in array :

```
NSArray *imageArray = @[image1, image2, image3]; //imageX are arbitrary name for images.
```

To view these images one by one, you need to load them and show in UIImageView:

```
//lets assume you have multiple buttons and all targeted to this method.
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender{ 
    NSInteger index = sender.tag;
    //here index is the integer to load the image. 

    if(index < imageArray.count){
        self.imageView setImage: imageArray[index]; 
    }
}
```